# Is there a way to get a new MacBook Pro (Max OSX Lion) with the Aqua style on it?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I am looking at Mac OSX Lion and I am not liking the fact that Aqua is gone. No more blue scrollbars, no more 3D look, no more beautiful Aqua design. (drop-downs, radios, scrollbars, etc.) I do not currently have a Mac but if I ever get one, (I highly want one, but they're too expensive for me to afford right now) I want the Aqua look back. Is there any way to do this? I really hope that there is.

Comment: I think you need to ask this when you finally get a Mac and have some experience with it. The lack of Aqua may quickly become a non-issue once you start using it.

Comment: @Philip Thanks for the downvote and close. :( How is this "not a real question"? Someone already answered and they answered fine. I'm pretty sure they didn't find any trouble trying to answer this.

Comment: Nathan, it might be due to the fact that you don't have a Mac (and have not even provided a time frame to get one). This makes the question a bit superfluous as even the answer is of little value to you now. Moreover, while there isn't a clear way to currently theme Lion, there might be by the time you get your machine. It actually helps you more if you hold off asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "official" way of changing it, though OSX is customizable with 3rd party apps. I researched around a bit and found out though that most of these apps won't work with Lion. Perhaps as time passes by Lion updates for these apps will be released, and perhaps you will be able to make Lion look however you want.

Here is a [page](http://www.maxthemes.com/) with some themes for both Mac OS and iOS. They provide a theme for Lion, the only one I could find.

Nevertheless, I should clarify:

Aqua is still there. The term "Aqua" refers to the whole UI of Mac OS X, including that of Lion. Over the years it [has changed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_%28user_interface%29), and it happened again in Lion. I too thought the Leopard-style aqua was better, but trust me, you will like the Lion Aqua.

Scrollbars hide automatically and they are meant to be discrete: having the blue scrollbars back would just defeat the purpose. Just the same, Lion tries to streamline elements such as tab views and progress bars that were perhaps to "obtrusive" to the eye, or called to much attention.

Im typing this from a machine with Lion, and can tell you you will love the new UI whenever you get your mac. Just give it a try! :) Designers at Apple did a great job to my opinion.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. But, I do miss the old drop-down menus. I think they took Aqua away a little too much. They really should have an option, as I prefer the glossy look rather than the flat buttons and stuff. Thanks for answering :)

Comment: Also, I don't really like the new exit/minimize buttons, they have no shadows :/ Well this wouldn't stop me from buying a Mac, but still.

Comment: I have to agree on the exit/minimize buttons. They were probably the first thing I noticed and the one I do think is looks much better on Snow Leopard. Drop down menus! Those are cool also in SL, but I admit taking the blue off and making them look more like buttons "unifies" the interface a bit. Anyways its all personal and I totally agree it shouldn't stop you from buying a Mac! Overall I think the Lion experience is so enjoyable this changes on Aqua stop being that big of a deal.

Comment: And yes. It would be great to have an option to change back to the old Snow Leopard look! :)

Comment: Yeah, one of the reasons why I like the scrollbar is because I'm so used to them and sometimes I like to click and drag it. Is it fine without the arrows at the bottom of the scrollbar?

Comment: Nathan: You can still click and drag the scrollbars in Lion, of course.

Comment: Hey, I just upgraded to Mountain Lion. Wow! The UI is much better than I thought. After using Snow Leopard for a few months I figured that I should probably upgrade and since Mountain Lion just came out I upgraded. I love the scroll bars, buttons, radio buttons, check boxes, etc. They basically look more refined and cleaner. And the scroll bars are awesome because they go away instead of taking up extra view port space. :)

Comment: Hey! Good to hear you joined us in the "new UI" and you like it. :) I'm a huge fan of the scrollbars too, they make everything look so much cleaner. I'm still on Lion, but will be upgrading to Mountain Lion soon. d: